# Question on insurance policy involving death benefit,endowment and premium vector

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

A $2$-year term insurance policy on $(60)$ provides for a death benefit of $100$ payable at the end of the year of death. This is purchased by a single premium. If $(60)$ lives to age $62$, the single premium is returned without interest. Given $q_{60}=0.1, q_{61}=0.15$, and interest is a constant $10%$, find the single premium.

---

Present value of death benefit

$A_{60}(100)=\sum b_k v(k+1) q_x$ $_k$$p_x=100(1.10)^{-2}$ X $0.15$ X $0.9=11.1570$

Present value of endowment

$a_{60}(P)=P(0.9)(0.85)(1.10)^{-2}$

Premium pattern

$a_{60}(P)=P$

$a_{60}(P)=A_{60}(100)+a_{60}(P)$

Hence P= 30.33

But the answer is $55.06$

Comment: Your first line is not a sum. I have an equation with a different result. But may it goes the right direction:[Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P%3D100*0.10%2F1.1%5E0%2B100*0.9*0.15%2F1.1%5E1%2B0.9*0.85*P%2F1.1%5E2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple enough that you can find the actuarial present value as follows:  with probability $q_{60} = 0.1$, $(60)$ dies in the first year, and the benefit paid is $100v$, where $v = (1+i)^{-1}$ is the annual present value discount factor.  With probability $p_{60} q_{61} = (0.9)(0.15)$, $(60)$ dies in the second year and the benefit paid is $100v^2$.  The only remaining possibility is if $(60)$ survives the term of the policy, in which case the premium is returned without interest, so the present value of this is $Pv^2$, which occurs with probability $p_{60} p_{61} = (0.9)(0.85)$.  Therefore, our equation of value is $$P = (0.1)(100v) + (0.9)(0.15)(100v^2) + (0.9)(0.85)(Pv^2).$$  Solving for $P$, we obtain $$P = \frac{100v(20+27v)}{200-153v^2}$$ and substituting $v = 0.90909$, we get $P = 4900/89 \approx 55.0562$ as claimed.